# How to override a method and pass parameters in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a public method in project and here is that method.

```
public bool SaveDocument(string customer)
{
//some codes
}
```

I have another project in same solution with this method

```
private void buttonSaveReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

button click event I need to pass 3 parameters (name,title,isbn) to SaveDocument() method and override it.I am having a difficulty with implementing this.Trying with this and can anyone help me out to complete it.

```
public class Ext : DocumentManager.DocumentManager
{
public override void SaveDocument()
{
base.SaveDocumentCustomer(customer);
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot override a method  that is not defined as "virtual".

Comment: You mean base class should be defined as "virtual"?

Comment: If you want to override method A, then method's A declaration should have the keyword "virtual". Ex: public virtual bool SaveDocument(string customer) is overridable, public bool SaveDocument(string customer) is not. As far as I know.